# Cesáro summation, prove convergence

Tags: fourier-analysis, cesaro-summable

Prove that if $a_k≥0$ and $\Sigma \, a_k$ is $(C,1)-summable$ (Cesáro summable), then the series is convergent in the usual sense. (Assume the contrary – what does that entail for a positive series?)

I can't really get the hang of this, I am in the beginning of my Fourier analysis course and we are laying the groundwork at the moment. I really want to understand this because I am thinking about taking a master in pure mathematics. Anyway, this is what I am thinking

Since $\Sigma \, a_k$ is $(C,1)$-summable we know that the value of

$$
\sigma_n=\frac{S_1+S_2+...+S_n}{n}
$$
has a finit value as $n$ tends to infinity.

Can I use this for something?

Comment: What properties of the sequence $(S_n)$ do you know?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking for? We can write that

$$
S_n = \Sigma_{k=1}^N a_k
$$

and we know that $a_k≥0$.

Comment: You want to show that $\sum a_k$ is convergent, that is, that the sequence $(S_n)$ is convergent. So think about some properties of sequences that are mentioned in connection with convergence, which of those do you know that $(S_n)$ has?

Comment: Maybe you can give me some more hints, I've been trying on my own since yesterday. haha

Comment: What does $a_k \geqslant 0$ tell you about $(S_n)$?

Comment: It tells me that the sum is either positive finit or goes to infinity.

Comment: What does it tell you about _the sequence_ $(S_n)$?

Comment: The series is the sum of the terms in the sequence but I'm not sure what that implies here. That it must have positive finite terms? I'm not that familiar with sequences, I know what they are but haven't worked with them so much, mostly series. 

From stated above I think we can say the the sequence is bounded is the series converge, right?

Comment: Monotonicity is a very important concept. Knowing that a sequence (or a function) is monotonic makes proving things about the sequence (or function) often much easier. Here, you can use the monotonicity to establish a relation between the sequence $(\sigma_k)$ and the sequence $(S_n)$ that easily yields the result.

Comment: Maybe you can show me how its done and then point me to some webpage with good information, because I don't even know what to search for now. There is nothing about this in my fourier analysis-book, that is for sure.

Comment: Now I came up with something, i think!

Since we know that $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sigma_n = S$$

and we can write $$\sigma_n =\frac{S_1+S_2+...+S_n}{n}=\frac{na_1+(n-1)a_2+...+a_n}{n} $$

and now when we let n go to infinity we are left with
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sigma_n = a_1+a_2+... = S
$$
And that gives us that $\Sigma \, a_k = S$

Comment: It's not quite so easy. Since the number of terms in the sum depends on $n$, you can't just take the limit of each term $\frac{n+1-k}{n}\cdot a_k$, you must prove that in this situation you can do that. In general, that doesn't work, since there are Cesàro-summable sequences such that $\sum b_k$ doesn't exist. Essentially, this exercise is about proving that it works for non-negative $a_k$. We know that $(S_n)$ is a monotonic sequence. When do monotonic sequences converge?

Comment: Yes, that is the things that mess it up for me. The fact that you can find cesáro sums for divergent series as well. I don't think I am able to solve this on my own.

But to you question, monotonic sequences converge when they are bounded, right?

Comment: Right. Monotonic sequences converge if and only if they are bounded. So we need to show that there is a $K$ with $S_n \leqslant K$ for all $n$. Any idea how you could use e.g. $\sigma_{2n}$ to bound $S_n$?

Comment: No sorry, I am clueless att this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a_k \geqslant 0$, the sequence

$$S_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n a_k$$

of partial sums is increasing (non-strictly in general). So it is convergent (to a real number) if and only if it is bounded.

We also know that if $(S_n)$ converges to $L\in \mathbb{R}$, then the sequence $(\sigma_n)$ of Cesàro means of $(S_n)$ also converges to $L$. So if the assertion we want to prove is true, then we can bound $(S_n)$ by $S = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sigma_n$. But we need not prove that sharp bound, any bound would do, and less sharp bounds might be easier to prove (here, there's no real difference; once you know the idea, all bounds are proved in essentially the same way).

The idea is that since $(S_n)$ is monotonically increasing, we can get a lower bound for $\sigma_m$ in terms of $S_n$ when $n \leqslant m$ by ignoring the $S_k$ for $k < n$ and replacing the $S_k$ for $k > n$ with $S_n$:

\begin{align}
\sigma_m &= \frac{1}{m}\sum_{k = 1}^m S_k\\
&\geqslant \frac{1}{m} \sum_{k = n}^m S_k\\
&\geqslant \frac{1}{m} \sum_{k = n}^m S_n\\
&= \frac{m - n + 1}{m} \cdot S_n.
\end{align}

Rearranging yields

$$S_n \leqslant \frac{m}{m-n+1}\cdot \sigma_m\tag{1}$$

for all $m \geqslant n$. Letting $m \to \infty$ in $(1)$, we obtain the sharp bound $S_n \leqslant S$ since $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty} \frac{m}{m-n+1} = 1$ and $\sigma_m \to S$.

If we take $m = 2n$ in $(1)$, we get the bound $S_n \leqslant 2 \sigma_{2n}$, which together with $\sigma_n \leqslant S_n$ shows that $(S_n)$ is bounded if and only if $(\sigma_n)$ is bounded without assuming that $(\sigma_n)$ converges, so either both converge or neither does.